# Monit delayed job failed to execute (RBENV)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean, delayed-job, rbenv, monit

This is my script looks like. I am not sure what's wrong with this script as monit just notified with short message ('delayed_job.1' failed to start)

```
check process delayed_job.1
  with pidfile /home/ubuntu/project_x/shared/pids/delayed_job.1.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin RAILS_ENV=production /home/ubuntu/project_x/current/bin/delayed_job -i 1 --queues=queue_1,queue_2 start --pid-dir=/home/ubuntu/project_x/shared/pids/"
  stop program = "/usr/bin RAILS_ENV=production /home/ubuntu/project_x/current/bin/delayed_job -i 1 --queues=queue_1,queue_2 stop --pid-dir=/home/ubuntu/project_x/shared/pids/"
  group delayed_job
```

Environment : Delayed Job + RBENV + Monit

This happens on production server.

Answer (score 0):

Monit was not able to start the program using the specified command. Did you test it work outside of Monit ?

Monit will wait 30 second before timeout on command execution. You can change it like

```
start program = "/etc/init.d/foobar start" with timeout 60 seconds
```

Also your stop command is the same as your start command, seems there is a typo in the stop command.

Comment: Yes it's working fine outside, I mean without monit I am able to execute command successfully!